# Using DHTMLX Scheduler, prevent tooltips from disappearing when hovering out of the event to the tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have been using the excellent DHTMLX Scheduler for a few days to get on with it, and I found solutions and workarounds for almost every specific things I wanted to achieve.

However, in this particular case, I am using the extension that allows tooltip customisation when hovering on an event ([see doc here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/tooltips.html)) which is working fine.

My problem here is the tooltip disappears when hovering out of the event, which is not wrong. The thing is I want to add clickable content in the tooltip, but since it disappears this simple task is rendered impossible.

I've searched through the docs, various forums and even here, but I haven't found any help regarding that matter.

Long story short, how can I prevent tooltips from disappearing when hovering above the tooltip itself (if at all possible)?

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tooltip dissapears (after some delay) when the mouse hovers on an empty space. I.e. if user could move a pointer from an event into the tooltip without pointing to the elements outside both tooltip and event - tooltip won't dissapear.

Try setting some configurations, so tooltip will appear closer to the pointer and user will be able to move cursor into it:

scheduler.tooltip.config.delta_x = 5;

scheduler.tooltip.config.delta_y = -5;

Comment: This is so bold I didn't even think about it. Your solution works perfectly, even if I had in mind a solution about timeout delays more than placement. However, that did the trick, so I'll select your answer. Thanks a lot!